# How can I set RefTex default reference format?

Tags: emacs, auctex, cleveref, reftex

I'm using RefTex and cleveref. When I want to add a cross-reference I need to enter `C-c ) C <SPC>` to select the uppercase (\Cref) reference format and show all label types. I use this method to search 99% of the time, so I would like to bind it to a key sequence or just set it as the default.

### EDIT

In the end I bound it to a fresh key, and do not override the standard behaviour. Instead I use a `let` of `reftex-refstyle`.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "reftex"
  '(progn
     (define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c c")
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (let ((reftex-refstyle "\\Cref"))
       (reftex-reference " "))))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking to the [`reftex-ref.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/textmodes/reftex-ref.el) source code I found the following (undocumented) solution: add to your `.emacs` the line

```lisp
(setq reftex-refstyle "\\Cref")
```

Please note that this will make `\Cref` the default reference command even when the `cleveref` isn't actually loaded.

If you want to skip the selection of the label type as well, you have to pass the argument `" "` to the `reftex-reference` function.  You can achieve that by binding <kbd>C-c )</kbd> to `(reftex-reference " ")`.  To do this, add also the following code to you `.emacs`

```lisp
(eval-after-load "reftex"
  '(progn
     (define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c )")
       (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (reftex-reference " ")))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, as long as I set the variable before opening my tex file. However, I still have to select the label type and I would be happy for it to just show all labels. Is this also possible?

Comment: @robin  See the updated answer `:-)`

Comment: Thanks this is great, I will give it a go on Monday. So if I wanted to bind this to a key without affecting the standard behaviour of `reftex-reference` would it be possible to wrap `(reftex-reference " ")` in a `let` of `reftex-refstyle`? I'm guessing this might not work as I seemed to have to set the variable before opening the tex file. I'll try it in any case!